# How to transform the $\tanh$ sigmoid function so that it starts from $f(0)=0$, goes asymptotically to $1$, and has $f(0.1)=a$ and $f(0.9)=b$?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

> How to transform the $\tanh$ sigmoid function so that it starts from $f(0)=0$, goes asymptotically to $1$, and has $f(0.1)=a$ and $f(0.9)=b$?

Is it possible with that function at all?

Comment: If by "transform" you mean apply an affine transformation to the argument of $f$ and its value, then it's not possible except for special values of $(a,b).$ The conceptual reason is that these transformations form a three-dimensional group but you are imposing four independent conditions on $f.$  Could you therefore please specify what you mean by "transform"?

Comment: @whuber I am sorry, your comment is too high level for me, I do not understand it, but I am very grateful for it. I use s-curves for practical application. I am in a search for s-curves with certain properties which allow for defining a priori s-curve parameters in reasonable ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from $$f(x)=p+q\tanh (rx+s)$$with $$\tanh(u)={e^{2u}-1\over e^{2u}+1}$$we obtain $$q,r>0$$
$${p+q=1\\p+q\tanh(s)=0\\
p+q\tanh(0.1r+s)=a\\
p+q\tanh(0.9r+s)=b\\
}$$which leaves us with a bunch of non-analytically solvable equations that should be coped numerically.

Comment: In general there are no solutions to these equations.

Comment: So TANH does not take part in the s-curves competition, which could be defined with interpretable parameters as defined in this question?https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3542734/624901

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want
$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}f(t)=0,\quad f(0.1)=a,\quad f(0.9)=b,\quad \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=1\ .$$
The limit conditions can be fulfilled with
$$f(t)={1+\tanh\bigl(c(t-t_0)\bigr)\over2},\quad c>0,\quad t_0\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
The parameters $c$ and $t_0$ adjust the time scale and have to be chosen such that your numerical data are met. This should be possible for arbitrary values $0<a<b<1$.

We obtain the equations
$$\eqalign{\tanh\bigl(c(0.1-t_0)\bigr)&=2a-1 \cr
\tanh\bigl(c(0.9-t_0)\bigr)&=2b-1\ , \cr}$$
or
$$\eqalign{c(0.1-t_0)&={\rm artanh}(2a-1) \cr
c(0.9-t_0)&={\rm artanh}(2b-1)\ . \cr}$$
The RHSs of the last equations are known real numbers. It is then easy to find $c$ and $t_0$. Note that the inverse of $\tanh$ can be calculated by
$${\rm artanh}(t)={1\over2}\log{1+t\over1-t}\qquad(-1<t<1)\ .$$

Comment: The question requires that $f(0)=0,$ not that $\lim_{t\to-\infty}f(t)=0.$  (Perhaps it has a typo and your interpretation, which is a natural one, was intended--but that's not what it actually says!)

Comment: @whuber: You are right. I shall leave my answer for the moment.

Comment: Thank you. But alas I would like f(0)=0.